# Web API default Routes

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm building a WebApi that will be host on the server with a separate Application pool and port.
What I want is that when I call the server name with the port like this: https://server:8443 to go directly in the webApi and use a specific controller and action.
My WebApiConfig is looking like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",

            defaults: new { controller = "Feedback", action = "GetFeedback", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

What I tried was to define a default controller and action when the server name is called. The problem here is that I get a 405 Method Not Allowed error.
Do you have any idea about how can I achieve something like this?
(I cannot use some URL path like https://server:8443/Controller/Action because this is exactly what I'm trying to eliminate).

Thank you!

Comment: you already have configured default as GetFeedback, can you share definition of it

Comment: **405 Method Not Allowed** means that you are calling your API using a different HTTP Verb than the one it is supported on the API definition. Your client can find the url, but is using an incorrect HTTP verb to access it. In other words, your API method is defined as a GET request and you are trying to do a POST, or something similar to that. Can you add your controller definition, as well as the way you are requesting your data that it returns your **405** error?